# Can't send fetched data to my socket.io stream?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to switch from single mysql-queries to mysql-pool connection, so users can share one mysql-connection, but I'm not familiar with this at all (also new to nodejs/socket.io).

The following code is what I've done so far to send data every second to the socket in an array:

```
var 
port                = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8000,
ip                  = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1',
app                 = require('http').createServer(handler),
fs                  = require('fs'),
request             = require('request'),
mysql               = require('mysql'),
moment              = require('moment'),
tz                  = require('moment-timezone'),
pool                = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit:    100,
host:               'xxx',
user:               'xxx',
password:           'xxx',
database:           'xxx',
debug:              false,
port:               3306}),
socketArray         = [],
POLLING_INTERVAL    = 1000,
pollingTimer;
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Berlin");

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.set('origins', '*:*');

function time()
{
output = new Date();
output = moment().format('(H:mm:ss.SS) ');
return output;
}

function handler(req,res) 
    {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.connection.setTimeout(0);
    res.end();
}
app.listen(port,ip);

function pollingLoop () {
    if (socketArray.length === 0) {
        // no connections, wait and try again
        setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
        return; // continue without sending mysql query
    }
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){ 
    if (err) { console.log({"code" : 100, "status" : "connection-db error"}); return; }   
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    console.log('socketArray length: ' + socketArray.length);

    var selection = 
        "SELECT\
        a.`id`,a.`product_id` AS pid,a.`random` AS nr,a.`price`,a.`price_end` AS pe,\
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),a.`datetime`) AS duration,\
        ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),b.`date`)) AS hb\
        FROM `auctions` AS a\
        LEFT JOIN `auctions_bids` AS b ON b.`auction_id` = a.`id`\
        WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),a.`datetime`) > '-1'\
        GROUP BY a.`id`\
        ORDER BY `duration` DESC,`id` DESC LIMIT 15";   
    var streamArray = [], lg = '';                      

    var query = connection.query(selection, function(err, results, rows){
    lg += ('id: '+results[0].id+' ('+results[0].duration+') ');         

    if 
    (
    ((results[0].duration < 2 || results[0].duration <= results[0].nr) && (results[0].price <= results[0].pe)) 
    ||
    ((results[0].duration < 2 || results[0].duration <= results[0].nr) && (results[0].hb > 0 && results[0].hb < 30))
    )   
    {
    min = 3;
    max = 5;
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    price = results[0].price+0.01;
    price = price.toFixed(2);

    pool.query('UPDATE `auctions` SET `random` = ?,`price` = ?, `datetime` = DATE_ADD(`datetime`,INTERVAL(17-TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),`datetime`))SECOND) WHERE `id` = ?',[rand, price, results[0].id]);  
    console.log(time()+'UPDATED id '+results[0].id+': random ('+rand+') price ('+price+'€)');   
    }       
    streamArray.push(results[0]);        

    updateSockets({ streamArray: streamArray });    
    console.log("auctions pushed: " + streamArray); 
    connection.release();
    setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);  
    });
    console.log(time()+lg+' C: '+socketArray.length);
}); 
}
pollingLoop();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    clearTimeout(pollingTimer);
    var socketIndex = socketArray.indexOf(socket);
    console.log(time()+'SOCKET-ID = %s DISCONNECTED', socketIndex);
    if (~socketIndex) { socketArray.splice(socketIndex, 1); }
    });  
    console.log(time()+'NEW SOCKET CONNECTED!');
    socketArray.push(socket);
}); 

var updateSockets = function(data) {
    socketArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) { tmpSocket.volatile.emit('stream', data); });
};

console.log(time()+'server.js executed\n');
```

But this doesn't send me any data to the WebSocket. Is this approach (code-structure) even correct? Previously I used `query.on('results')` to get data like this:

```
var selection = "SELECT * FROM auctions";            
var query = mysql.query(selection), auctions = []; 
query.on('result', function(auction) {
console.log('id: '+auction.id+' ('+auction.duration+') ');
});
```

This worked fine showing data with `auction.row` but how to do this in my mysql pool connection?

Also after some seconds I'm getting an error that `release()` isn't even defined, but it's listed in the mysql-module documentation... so I think my whole logical process is somehow incorrect.

1. Should I use connection.end() and .release() at all? Because the
   connection should never end.
2. Should I still use `setInterval(function () { mysql.query('SELECT

   1'); }, 5000);` as answered in another StackOverflow question to keep
   the connection alive here? ([nodejs mysql Error: Connection lost The server closed the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection))

(Appreciate any tips or answers to even some of my questions! Better some answers than none, because I experienced that this topic isn't answered much at all.)

**EDIT:** 
Updated my whole code (see above). Output looks like this now: http://s21.postimg.org/avsxa87rb/output.jpg

So the stream gets the data, but in the console.log is nothing and there's this javascript error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating a pool, and using getConnection on that pool. Then, when you're done with the connection, release it. Additionally, you do not need to stop the pollingLoop or start it for each connection, one loop is enough.

I didn't understand the if statement with conditions, so i omitted it. It likely needs to go somewhere else.

```
var socketArr = [];

function handler(req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.connection.setTimeout(0);
    res.end();
}
app.listen(port, ip);
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'example.org',
    user     : 'bob',
    password : 'secret'
});

function pollingLoop () {
    if (socketArr.length === 0) {
        // no connections, wait and try again
        setTimeout(pollingLoop, 1000);
        return; // continue without sending mysql query
    }
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log({
                "code": 100,
                "status": "Error in connection database"
            });
            return;
        }
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
        var selection = "SELECT * FROM auctions";
        var streamArray = [],
            lg = '';
        var query = connection.query(selection, function (err, results, fields, rows) {
            lg += ('id: ' + results[0].id + ' (' + results[0].duration + ') ');
            /*if (conditions) {
                var query_update = connection.query('UPDATE `auctions` SET `price` = ? WHERE `id` = ?', [price, auction.id]);
                console.log(time() + 'UPDATED id ' + auction.id + ': price (' + price + '€)');
            }*/
            streamArray.push(results);
            updateSockets({
                streamArray: streamArray
            });
            console.log("auctions pushed: " + streamArray);
            connection.release();
            setTimeout(pollingLoop, 1000);
        });
        console.log(time() + lg + ' C: ' + socketArr.length);
    });
}
// start loop
pollingLoop();

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = socketArr.indexOf(socket);
        console.log(time() + 'SOCKET-ID = %s DISCONNECTED', socketIndex);
        if (~socketIndex) {
            socketArr.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        }
    });
    console.log(time() + 'NEW SOCKET CONNECTED!');
    socketArr.push(socket);
});
var updateSockets = function (data) {
    socketArr.forEach(function (tmpSocket) {
        tmpSocket.volatile.emit('stream', data);
    });
};
```

Comment: So this is my output now with this code of yours: http://s21.postimg.org/avsxa87rb/output.jpg

Comment: It doesn't seem to get the data like it should be.