# Remove a square bracket and receiving JSON properly in nodejs/websocket enviroment?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, multidimensional-array, websocket

At the moment I can only output data of a specific key (index) with `console.log(auction[index].id);` but I need the data using `console.log(auction.id);`. How do I accomplish this?

I'm using nodejs and my WebSocket receives data just like this:

```
42["stream",{"streamArray":[[{"id":20,"pid":2,"nr":4,"price":5.73,"pe":506.08,"duration":14,"hb":361262},{"id":23,"pid":17,"nr":4,"price":5.59,"pe":189.13,"duration":7,"hb":null},{"id":12,"pid":8,"nr":3,"price":5.59,"pe":90.23,"duration":7,"hb":null}]]}]
```

So it's a multidimensional array. And I think there's one square bracket too much? (Right before `{"id":20` for example)

This way I receive the data client-side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/',{'forceNew':true });
socket.on('stream', function (data) {
$.each(data.streamArray,function(index,auction){
```

Do I have to change the code before the data is even sent to my WebSocket or can I solve this issue client-side to receive the correct data in my variable `auction`? How could I solve this?

**EDIT:**

This is the relevant server-side code:

```
function pollingLoop () {
    if (socketArray.length === 0) {
        // no connections, wait and try again
        setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
        return; // continue without sending mysql query
    }
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){ 
    if (err) { console.log({"code" : 100, "status" : "connection-db error"}); return; }   
    console.log('connected as ' + connection.threadId);

    var selection = 
        "SELECT * FROM auctions";   
    var streamArray = [], lg = '';  // init of array and log variable                   
        var query = connection.query(selection, function(err, fields, results){

        for (i=0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            lg += (fields[i].id+' ('+fields[i].duration+') '+fields[i].price+'€ -');    

            if (somecondition)  
            {
            // mysql update here
            }       
        }
        streamArray.push(fields);
        updateSockets({ streamArray: streamArray });    
        connection.release();
        setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);  
        console.log(time()+lg+' C: '+socketArray.length);
        });
    }); 
    }
        pollingLoop();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    clearTimeout(pollingTimer);
    var socketIndex = socketArray.indexOf(socket);
    console.log(time()+'SOCKET-ID = %s DISCONNECTED', socketIndex);
    if (~socketIndex) { socketArray.splice(socketIndex, 1); }
    });  
    console.log(time()+'NEW SOCKET CONNECTED!');
    socketArray.push(socket);
}); 

var updateSockets = function(data) {
    socketArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) { tmpSocket.volatile.emit('stream', data); });
};
```

Comment: If you think there's a bracket too much, you should fix your serverside code (and if you need help with that, you'll need to show it). Otherwise, if the multidimensional array makes sense, just nest two loops.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it makes sense. The case is that I've rewritten my server-side code and noticed that there was one square-bracket less before than it is at the moment. That's why I have to use `auction[index].id` instead of `auction.id` now. And there is another loop to create a countdown timer later on, so I'm not sure if I should create an additional loop client-side or if that would slow down the browser of a user even more? And I have to say I'm pretty new to javascript/nodejs.

Comment: Looks like it should just be one Array of Objects. Fix it Server Side. Shouldn't that be `auction[index][0].id` anyways? `auction[index]` should be each Array. This is an Array which contains another Array of Objects.

Comment: I added the server-side code. The data comes from a MySQL-database and will be pushed to `streamArray`. @Bergi

Comment: No, then it says: `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` when I'm adding [0] after [index] @PHPglue

Comment: Seems like you are getting the correct data using `auction[index]` then? How can you be sure which Object you are getting the `id` of otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

> ```
>     streamArray.push(fields);
>     updateSockets({ streamArray: streamArray });
> ```

It does create the one-slot array that is superfluous. My guess is that you either wanted to move the `streamArray.push(…)` inside of the `for` loop (and then push `fields[i]` or something), or you just should do

```
 updateSockets({ streamArray: fields });
```

and omit all `streamArray` code.

Comment: Great, thank you! Could you also answer me a more off-topic question as you've already looked into my server-code? Do you know why `console.log('connected as ' + connection.threadId);` outputs two unique ids like two users are connected to my website? But in reality it's only me with one tab visiting my website. This is about mysql pooling and I want to keep this connection alive and shared to all users visiting the website but as a single mysql-connection.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what the `.threadId` means, I'd have to read docs/code as well.