# Server NodeJs crashes in idle time and how do I fix it?

Tags: mysql, node.js

My server api is on alwayse alwaysdata.
After x time the server crash.

```
events.js:183
  throw er;
 // Unhandled 'error' eventError: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

I'm looking at whether this could not be related to a mysql error. but pre-existing posts do not help me. I think the server mysql cut the connection I do not know why. 
here I establish the connection:

```js
let con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "alwaysdata.net",
            user: "user",
            password: "",
            database: "database"
        });

        try {
            con.query(check, (err, customer) => {
            if (err){
                console.log("%s Error on check query",Date());
                throw err;
            }
```

Comment: Did you try to simulate the scenario by terminating or closing the mysql server?

Comment: Consider posting the last 400 lines of your MySQL error log and your my.cnf OR my.ini

Answer (score 2):

try connection pool:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
let pool  = mysql.createPool(
    {
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host : '172.17.0.1',
        port : 3306,
        user : 'test',
        password : 'test',
        database : 'test',
        multipleStatements: true
    }
);

...
pool.query(sql, params, function(err, rows) {
...
```

it works stably on my versions of mysql 5.7 and 8

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways you can handle this.

- 1) Force MySQL to keep the connection alive (not official, but I believe will do the trick).
- 2) Handle the mysql server disconnect from the Node's point of
  view.

For both there is an excellent example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection).

> Server disconnects
>
> You may lose the connection to a MySQL server due to network problems,
>   the server timing you out, the server being restarted, or crashing.
>   All of these events are considered fatal errors, and will have the
>   err.code = 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'. See the Error Handling section
>   for more information.
>
> Re-connecting a connection is done by establishing a new connection.
>   Once terminated, an existing connection object cannot be re-connected
>   by design.
>
> With Pool, disconnected connections will be removed from the pool
>   freeing up space for a new connection to be created on the next
>   getConnection call.

Answer (score 0):

```
let connection=null;
function handleDisconnect() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "alwaysdata.net",
        user: "user",
        password: "",
        database: "database"
    }); // Recreate the connection, since
    // the old one cannot be reused.

    connection.connect(function (err) { // The server is either down
        if (err) { // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
            console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
            setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
        } // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
    }); // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
    // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('db error', err);
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
            handleDisconnect(); // lost due to either server restart, or a
        } else { // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
            throw err; // server variable configures this)
        }
    });
}
handleDisconnect();
setInterval(function () {
    connection.query('SELECT 1');
}, 5000);

module.exports = connection;
```

you export the connection object and use this for the other connection queries.

I have called a Query every 5sec to keep the connection alive, i have tried all other approaches and this works like a charm.

Comment: use require('mysql'); ?

Comment: question, how do I kill the loop between each call?

Comment: which each call.

Comment: here, at each call. he will create a loop. Forcibly I will find myself with ping all the time. my function is a post

Comment: you export the connection object and reuse the same. In that way only one object will be made and once the loop will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Manish's answer worked for me!

I've been struggling with this for the past two days. I had a nodejs server with mysql db running on my localhost and after migrating to heroku with cleardb addon I came across several issues. I had this code in a config file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    database: 'database',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password', });
module.exports = db;
```

I changed it to what Manish mentioned to handle the disconnect.