# Node.js - server closed connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server

I'm running a `node.js` server but I'm also running - but too bad straight into a really **big** bug:

**Exactly** every eight hours the server closes connection, crashes and produces this error message:

```
{ Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/node/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1092:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
```

---

I'm aware that this error comes from `mysql` so I spent a few hours googling for solutions. But for me none of them seems to work.

- Catching the error `PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST`

---

```
con.on('error', function(err) {
    mysqlConnection();
})

con.on('close', function(err) {
    mysqlConnection();
})

function mysqlConnection() {
  con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "xy",
      user: "xy",
      password: "xy",
      database: "xy",
  });
  con.connect(function(error) {})
}
```

- Sending queries in timeout `(3,600,000)`

---

```
setInterval(function () {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM xy", [], (err,result,fields)=>{})
}, 3600000); // every hour
```

- simulating the connection drop

---

```
con.destroy();
```

It seems that no-one of the fixes is working for me. So I hope I can get an update to some already [outdated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection) & [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28215691) I found.

Comment: any details other then this so far ? i am having the same problem, guess only option is to increase wait timeout from mysql.