# Node events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get an error when requesting an API and it crashes on any win server. Can anybody help, please?

This is part of my code:

```
app.get("/js/2806/api/products/getAllDrugs", (req, res) => {


    const connection = getDBConnection()

    const queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_drug";

    connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log("Failed to query for drugs: " + err);
            // res.sendStatus(500);
            res.json({
                ErrorDetail: {
                    code: -1,
                    msg: err.code
                }
            });
            res.end();
            return
        }

        const drugs = rows.map((row) => {
            return {
                id: row.id,
                storeId: row.drugStoreId,
                drugName: row.drugName,
                description: row.drugDsc,
                drugUsing: row.drugUsing,
                drugDoseId: row.drugDoseId,
                categoryId: row.categoryId
            };
        })

        res.json({
            ErrorDetail: {
                code: 0
            },
            Response: drugs
        })
    })


});
```

> Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. at Protocol.end (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\CaptainCure\n s\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:112:13) at Socket. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Captain odules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:97:28) at Socket. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Captain odules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10) at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) Emitted 'error' event at: at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\ ainCure\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:425:8) at Protocol.emit (events.js:189:13) at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Ca node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:390:10) at Protocol.end (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\CaptainCure\n s\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:116:8) at Socket. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Captain odules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:97:28) I— lines matching original stack trace ...] at process._tickCallback Cinternal/process/next_tick.js:63:19> [nodemon I - wait in is (nodemon] si ing 'node app.js -erver is running on port: 3000 ode events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event is (nodemon] starting 'node app.js' -erver is running on port: 3000

Comment: can you show us what is getDBConnection() function returning?

Comment: @R.Sarkar `function getDBConnection(){

  return mySql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '***',
    database: 'captaincure'
  })
  
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection hope this will help you

Answer (score 6):

Because of the server is already running on back so we do have to restart.
 and if your using both iterm and the terminal so you need to make sure that the you use only one other one you have to close.

Comment: Always one terminal is open and one process is using from my port