# The mysql server disconnects every night, how do I resolve it?

Tags: mysql, node.js, disconnect

I leave my computer on 24 hours, but I still lose connection with the `MySQL` server. My WiFi runs smoothly and is never disconnected because I'm still able to use the internet along with my other electronics. The error message says

> The server closed the connection.

Is this inferring a problem on my computer/connection or with `MySQL`? Or is it my codes? Please advise.

**Error messages:**

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:97:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:426:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:116:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:97:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**My codes:**

```
let con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: 'db',
  dateStrings: 'date',
});

const handleDisconnect = () => {
  con.connect(err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
  });

  con.on('err', err => {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
      handleDisconnect();
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
}

handleDisconnect();
```

Comment: I hope this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection) helps you.

Comment: This sounds like a timeout. Does your node.js-client do something regularly (e.g. does it rest during night cause there are no (or less) new messages/stock quotes/..., and the disconnect happens then?) Also, i'm not entirely sure: does your code reconnect properly and you are asking why it has to reconnect, or does your code stop working after this disconnect and you need a fix for this?

Comment: @Solarflare It just randomly disconnects overnight and I can reconnect it again the following morning I wake up. The computer is on overnight but it still disconnects. The codes don't seem to handle the error when it disconnects to the MySQL server.

Comment: @CCC Thank you, it seems like I'm missing a single line of code. hopefully it fixes my problem.