# Trouble connecting Node.js to XAMPP MySQL server on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, node.js, macos, xampp

Ive been struggling with connecting Node.js, using the MySql module, to my MySql DB. The DB is being ran locally through XAMPP on my Mac. Here is my connection script

```
var mysql_con = mysql.createConnection({
        socketPath: '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
        //port: '8080',
        host: '192.168.64.2',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'twitch_versus'
});
mysql_con.connect(function (err) {
        if(err) {
                console.log('mysql connect error: ' + err.stack);
                return;
        }
        console.log('mysql connected as ' + mysql_con.threadId);
});
```

Running this config gives this error

```
mysql connect error: Error: connect ENOENT /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/bot.js:24:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Ive tried using the socket path and also the default port,  as well as port 8080. I've tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the ip you see above. My my.cnf does not contain bind-address field and skip networking is commented out. When using the port 8080 and localhost I get this error after around 30 seconds

```
mysql connect error: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/tcv/bot.js:24:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

running

```
mysql status
```

returns

```
UNIX socket:        /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Like always any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1: added my.cnf

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /opt/lampp/var/mysql) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        =3306
socket      =/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
user=mysql
port=3306
socket      =/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=1M
table_open_cache=64
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M


# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
# Deprecated in 5.6
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
```

EDIT 2: I think Ive made progress with the help from the comments. I'm testing with the following code, its just a connection script

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "192.168.64.2",
  user: "root",
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

this throws

```
Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gabrielraichart/Documents/tcv/test.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
  fatal: true
```

using nc -vz 192.168.64.2 3306 gives a successful connection message

Comment: can you share us your my.cnf ???

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection#answer-20211143)?

Comment: @WEBjuju yes, did not fix it.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar just did

Comment: Add bellow [mysqld] this : 
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0   later restart MySQL

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar added, restarted and still no connection

Comment: telnet 192.168.64.2 3306

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar setting host to that and with port 3306 as well as having bind-address = 0.0.0.0 I get the error                                                                                             mysql connect error: Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0

Comment: I know, I just try to tell you that validate with telnet if the port is open .... from the machine where your script is located ... open the console and run an  telnet IP_Server_Mysql 3306 ... if the connection is rejected ... It's just a matter of lowering the firewall

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I apologize for the misunderstanding, using nc -vz 192.168.64.2 3306 I get connection succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by granting access to all databases in mysql.

Comment: how you did that

Comment: what do you mean? how to do it?

Comment: ```GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';``` @Reza Zeraati

Answer (score 3):

I also had this error on my machine while I was trying to login with `root`. The issue was that XAMPP was running in its own VM, so his `localhost` was different from my Mac's `localhost`. I've fixed it by creating a new user in `phpMyAdmin` having the host name `%`, so it can be accessed from wherever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macos with M1 chip, go for this:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

let pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'database-name',
}).promise();

module.exports = pool;
```