# aws linux server crashing after deployment

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, pm2

I have been running my **reactJS** website for about one year so far and there's server crashing happened(this start to happen in the last 3 months) when each time I did a deployment(after doing the deployment it works fine but) & on the next day morning when I tried to log in to my website I couldn't access it & I have to restart my **PM2** server to make it work again. but from last week my whole **AWS** instance crashed  & I can't find why that happened, from last week this happened to me 2 times. then I have to go to AWS web and restart the server(before I have started using the console but since now I couldn't access it via console have to go to the AWS web and start it again).

also when 1st-time server crashing happens I got that my MySQL server closed the connection since I got it from the logs:

`db error Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. at Protocol.end (/home/ubuntu/CIAO_ERP/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13) at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/CIAO_ERP/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28) at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/CIAO_ERP/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) at Socket.emit (events.js:215:7) at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) { fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }`

then I have used this solution :[stackoverflow answer for handling 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20211143/8931996)

then I handled that issue but still, a connection loss appears.

anyway, I'm attaching my connection handling and my server code segments to check whether if I did anything wrong!

SERVER.js

```
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");

const { DBConnect } = require("./connection");

DBConnect();

const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 })
);

app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/invoiceSetting", require("./routes/api/InvoiceSetting"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
app.use("/api/appSetting", require("./routes/api/AppSetting"));
app.use("/api/StakeHolder", require("./routes/api/StakeHolderSetting"));
app.use("/api/warehouse", require("./routes/api/WarehouseSetting"));
app.use("/api/production", require("./routes/api/ProductionSetting"));
app.use("/api/purchasing", require("./routes/api/Purchasing"));
app.use("/api/purchasingTemp", require("./routes/api/PurchasingTemp"));

//serve static assets if in production

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../..", "build")));


const port = process.env.PORTADDRESS || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${port}`)).on(
    "error",
    (err) => {
        console.log(`catched error on listen & error is   ${err}\n`);
       
    }
);
```

here is my DB connection handling code

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

let portDB = process.env.PORT_DB;
console.log("PORT ENV VARIABLE:", portDB);
if (portDB === undefined) {
    process.exit();
}

var db_config = {
    host: process.env.HOST_NAME,
    user: process.env.USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    multipleStatements: true,
    port: portDB,
};

let db = mysql.createConnection(db_config);

const handleDisconnect = () => {
    db = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
    db.connect((err) => {
        // The server is either down
        if (err) {
            // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
            console.log("error when connecting to db:", err);
            console.log("& restarting");
            setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
        } // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
        else {
            console.log("Connected Mysql DB!");
        }
    }); // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
    // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
    db.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("db error", err);
        if (err.code === "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST") {
            console.log(`err.code : PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST appeard\n`);
            // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
            handleDisconnect(); // lost due to either server restart, or a
        } else {
            // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
            console.log(`db.on("error") else called & err : ${err}\n`);
            throw err; // server variable configures this)
        }
    });
};



module.exports = {
    db: db,//this db is used to handling mysql queries 
    DBConnect: handleDisconnect,//this is used to start the db 
};
```

I would be glad if any help me to solve this server crashing problem or whole AWS instance crashing problem I'm facing right now :(

Comment: could be mysql running out of ram. FInd the mysql logs and include these in your question. Check ram usage while logged into the server. Include AWS instance size and my.cnf configuration items on the server.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a Skype ID?

Comment: Thanks for the help! we are moving from aws to our own servers so hope this problem will solve that!