# nodejs mysql on pool connection Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

My question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection) but the solution didnt work for me probably because im using a different type of mysql connection (pool). This is my code:

```
    let config= {
        host: '***',
        user: 'admin',
        password: '***',
        port: '3306',
        database: '***',
        multipleStatements: true
    };

const con = mysql.createPool(config);
select();
function select(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else
                console.log("Connected!");
            let sql = "SELECT * FROM bidPrice WHERE idExchangePlatform = 2;";
            connection.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
                connection.release();
                connection.destroy();
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(results)
                resolve(results);
            });

        });
    });
}
```

I also important to mention that im running this function using the following command

node --max-old-space-size=31744 index.js # Increase to 31 GB

This is because im working with millions of records from the database query If i run this with regular node command i would be getting `Javascript heap out of memory`

When i tried integrating the solution i mentioned earlier to my code i just get a "killed" log after a while and then the process stops, should i handle server disconnect in a different way when using mysql.pool?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need all the records? or is there some processing/filtering that you should be doing in SQL? I doubt you are pushing these all to the the user. Is there an index that begins with `idExchangePlatform` in your table `bidPrice`?