# Nextjs api route internal error in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, mysql2

All apis are working just fine when serving locally but when i try to deploy the app in vercel/ heroku, the apis give me internal error code 500.

So i tried to make a "test api " called hello, it worked just fine until i tried to open connection with db ( query was working locally but in production it gave me internal error)

Here is my code

```
const mysql= require("mysql2/promise")
export default async function hello(req, res) {
  const db= await mysql.createConnection({
    host:"eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net",
    user:"########",
    password:"####",
    database:'####',
    port:'3306',
  })

  const [results] = await db.execute("select * from ##",[])
  db.end()
  res.json(results)
}
```

[image: Here is heroku log]

Update: On heroku, the api is taking 10 seconds to respond back

Comment: Have you seen the logs of your server in production? If you have no logs, then install a logging library and start logging because that's your only way of debugging production bugs, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/writing-best-practices-for-application-logs

Comment: Okay now it saying that the server closed the connection (mysql2)

Comment: You mean `Connection refused` or `Connection reset`? Can you show us the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Done , i uploaded the image

Comment: Does the same error happen on Vercel?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210522/nodejs-mysql-error-connection-lost-the-server-closed-the-connection

Comment: I cant check the logs in vercel for some reasons ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247395/discussion-between-niceman-and-ahmad-al-maaz).